# C++ Euler Approximation

Tags: c++, approximation

Why does my code only go up to 2.4 for the x value as the output when I enter 0.1 as the step size? If I enter a value like .01 or .001 it goes up to 2.5.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std; 
int main() {
    double step; 
    double x0 = 1.0; 
    double y0 = 1.0; 
    double diffY; 
    std::cout << std::fixed;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(2);
    cout << "Enter step value: ";
    cin >> step; 
    while (x0 <= 2.5 ) {

        diffY = x0 + ((3*y0) / x0);
        cout << x0 << "    " << y0 << "\n"; 
        x0+=step;
        y0+=step*(diffY);
    }

    return 0; //initially defined the main function to return an int
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should loop using integer-based limits, and inside the loop, scale the values down.  Otherwise your loop may run a differing number of times depending on compiler, compiler options, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Good old fashion floating point number errors, print out to a high precision your `x0`, you will get this:

```
1.1000000000000001
1.2000000000000002
...
2.4000000000000012
2.5000000000000013
```

Note how on your last past, you will increment **past** 2.5 therefore will not execute your last loop. This is because floating point numbers are binary (base 2) not decimal (base 10) so they cant represent every number exactly. This includes `0.1`.

You should always use an epsilon when comparing floating point numbers:

```
float eps = step/100; // Only an example.
while (x0 <= 2.5 + eps ) {
    ...
```

For more info, [read this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). If you want to play, [here is a live example.](http://ideone.com/G4sp59)

Comment: *"This is because floating point numbers are binary (base 2) not decimal (base 10) so they cant represent every number exactly."* That holds for any integer base (given finitely many digits).

Comment: I suggest not looping with floating point loop counters whatsoever.  By hook or by crook, get those loop constraint values to be integer.